Is a linear map determined by the image of an orthonormal basis?
I have just recently started learning about infinite dimension vector spaces: in particular, Hilbert spaces.
I have read about the concept of an orthonormal basis, the difference with respect to a Hamel basis is that we now allow infinite linear combinations, that is, any vector can be written as a convergent series involving the basis elements.
My questions are:

Suppose we have a Hilbert space $X$ and a linear map $T:X\to X$. Suppose that we have an orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$ and that we know $T(e_i)$ for every $i\in I$. Can we determine the image of any other vector by $T$? How do we ensure the resulting series is convergent?

Suppose we have some other subset $\{u_i\}_{i\in I}$. Is there some linear map $f$ such that $f(e_i)=u_i$ for $i\in I$?




Not unless $T$ is continuous, or equivalently bounded. It's a theorem that every vector in $X$ is the sum of a convergent series in an orthonormal basis, and then by continuity $T$ preserves this sum. 2. Under the hypothesis that $T$ is continuous, it must be bounded, so this is not possible if the norms $| u_i |$ are not bounded.


@QiaochuYuan Thanks. And for $2$, what happens if they are indeed bounded?

Then there's no problem if the $u_i$ are orthogonal. If the $u_i$ aren't orthogonal then I think there can still be problems.

Good question. The answer is "yes" for continuous linear operators.
See this wikipedia page.

Thanks. So we can have several discontinuous linear maps which send the orthonormal basis to the same elements?

I think so. But it's been a long time since I did any rigorous functional analysis.
